# Can a Nikon D3500 shutter be released remotely without using the Snapbridge app?

Tags: nikon, dslr, remote, shutter-release, snapbridge

I have Nikon D3500 DSLR. It does not have a wired remote port or an IR receiver port for traditional remote control. I can use the Snapbridge application but it is annoying as it gets disconnected every time. The Nikon D3400 has remote shutter control.

Are there other alternatives besides the Snapbridge app so I can remotely release the shutter in my D3500?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Officially, the only way to remotely trigger your D3500 is with the Snapbridge app.

Unofficially, and if you consider USB-connected to be "remote", you can control some of the functions of your camera using qDSLRDashboard on either your computer or your Android device, tethered via USB cable (to PC) or USB-on-the-go cable (to Android).

The D3xxx line isn't officially supported by qDSLRDashboard, but it reportedly works for some limited functionality, according to this [dpreview.com forum post](https://www.dpreview.com/forums/thread/4360125#forum-post-62212652):

> If you have a USB-OTG adapter/cable, I recommend the QDSLRDashboard app for PC and mobile. The D3XXX cameras aren't officially supported, but basic functionality works for me. Live View and video recording don't work, but you have full control over the basic camera settings and you can use the built-in bracketing feature. I think it's well worth the $9 for mobile, despite the limitations for our camera.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to control the shutter remotely (to be more pricise via microUSB cable), while watching the liveview of the camera (D3500), using "Camera Connect & Control" (Android).
It costs 9 euros and it also offers a free trial, so that you can make sure that things work at your end.

Answer (score 0):

I use "Camera Connect & Control" too, by connecting the camera through USB (OTG). It works well: it allows you to watch the liveview from the smartphone's display, shot in timelapse mode and control almost evrerything. The only problem I get is that I can't use the BULB mode, but for me it's not a big fault.